# How to automatically update content to homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, push

From what I can see with a site like Pinterest, each of the containers on the main page are pulling data from containers on individual pages. But what sort of system would you use to automatically push the content from the individual page content to the main page once that individual page is created? Is there a system or software I could use tat handles this?

Additional details:
I would like to create a system where i upload content (let's say a link and the link's description) to a new page on the server. I would then like to have the main page of the site (where all the traffic will be) to show the data from that new page (and all other new pages I create) automatically.

Note: 
When referencing Pinterest, it is **NOT** the grid type layout I'm wondering about or it's design. It's the integral system which could be fashioned after their model of *new user created content pushed to the front page.*

Comment: websocket or SSE may be useful

Comment: It's not really pulling data from containers on individual pages, it's just storing that data globally and being able to iterate through the data in different ways. Wordpress would be my suggestion.

Comment: you're looking for a CMS.

Comment: Easy with AMD - http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/ and your "hoempage" is just stating which modules to load where. they themselves are independent. (theoretically can talk with each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Content Management System (CMS) like [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) to handle something like this for you. You could allow users to post from the front end using a plugin or custom coding and then have them show on the homepage using a blog feed.

WordPress is a very powerful system that can do just about anything, it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answer! I actually just uploaded Wordpress but wasn't sure if it could handle this. Although, I should have been more specific when it came to using the term, user; I would be the only user uploading content.

Comment: @mikejoelbuchanan In this case it would be even easier, WordPress has an admin panel which is really user friendly. You'll be up and running in no time :)

Comment: Perfect thank you. As a side note, do you believe that Wordpress could handle a system of multiple feeds pertaining to different categories? See this example for what I am trying to achieve: http://paper-parcel.com/images/layout.gif

Comment: @mikejoelbuchanan Yes it can, you could set up different categories or post types and have separate feeds for each if you so wished, or you could show any combination of categories in a single feed. You may have to read up on the WordPress Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/ to get started but it is fairly easy to use if you know PHP. I personally build 90% of my websites on WordPress and rarely come across any limitations.